# Array causing Run time error 13 type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting the Runtime error 13 on the line `For i = LBound(buyArrayLow) To UBound(buyArrayLow)`, there are values in `buyArrayLow` and `buyArrayHigh`.

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
Dim buyRngLow As Range
Dim buyRngHigh As Range
Dim buyArrayLow As Variant
Dim buyArrayHigh As Variant
Dim TempAr() As String

Set buyRngLow = Range("D" & lStartBuyRange)
Set buyRngHigh = Range("D" & lEndBuyRange)

buyArrayLow = buyRngLow.Value
buyArrayHigh = buyRngHigh.Value

For i = LBound(buyArrayLow) To UBound(buyArrayLow)
  For j = LBound(buyArrayHigh) To UBound(buyArrayHigh)
    If buyArrayLow(i, 1) = buyArrayHigh(j, 1) Then
      boolFound = True
      Exit For
    End If
  Next j

  If boolFound = False Then
    ReDim Preserve TempAr(n)
    TempAr(n) = buyArrayLow(i, 1)
    n = n + 1
  Else
    boolFound = False
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `Set buyRngLow = Range("D2:D" & lStartBuyRange)` ?

Comment: The reason your code errors is that the `Value` property of a single cell range is not an array at all (therefore `L/UBound` fail) The root cause is probably that you haven't set up your ranges to match the data properly

Comment: @chrisneilsen granted but I was trying to fix both the x and y issues of an x/y problem.

Comment: ^^As above and if not sorted please share some data